# OSError: [Errno 6] Device not configured

Tags: python, macos, jupyter

Using Python in Jupiter notebook in Anaconda and trying to access files on an external hard drive. I can access the hard drive using:

os.chdir('/Volumes')
but when I try to list the directories, I get the following error:

OSError: [Errno 6] Device not configured

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, for me, the reason of the error, was a server connection lost. After the disconnection, the name of the path changed and the copy of the file failed.